# List index is not compatible with all screens

Tags: android, android-layout

Am trying to create list index as same as in android contacts but it is not compatible with all screens.
Am using linear layout.The following screenshots will explain the scenario

The list index appeared in various screens

[image]

The index is working perfectly in xhdpi screen.

Each element is a textview and it is vertically aligned in a linear layout. while we switching to different screens it is displayed as misaligned as shown in the figure.

The linear layout defined in the activity xml is follows

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/sideIndex"
        android:layout_width="30dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
        android:orientation="vertical" >
  </LinearLayout>
```

I have added the textview to the linear layout in a following way

```
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1);
TextView indexComp = new TextView(this);
indexComp .setText(indexLetter);
indexComp .setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
indexComp .setLayoutParams(params);
index.addView(indexComp);
```

Is it possible to create an index compatible with all screen ?

If so please guide me.

please help ASAP.

Thank you so much for your valuable time

Amith

Comment: have you  tried using android:layout_height="wrap_content"

Comment: @nit Yes The code is LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1);

Comment: I don't undertand your image, its not very descriptive of what the problem is.. could you expound on what you mean?

Comment: @please ZOOM the page the text(A,B,C,.....) is not displaying properly while switching screens